# Start App from terminal with focus

Tags: macos

I start my firefox with a fixed profile from terminal using:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -P UserName
```

It works nicely, but the focus is on Terminal and not on firefox.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following instead:

```
open -n /Applications/Firefox.app --args -no-remote -P UserName
```

`-n` means a new instance of the application is launched, even if there's already one open. Everything after `--args` is being passed on as arguments to the application.

Comment: `-a` can be used in place of `-n`.  This will reuse the existing process, but will still bring the window to the front and give it focus.

Answer (score 1):

A kludgy hack would be to add the following after the command:

```
& osascript -e 'tell application "Firefox"' -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
```

Or alternatively you could use `open /Applications/Firefox.app` if you don't need to specify the profile you want to use.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I like the first hint. 
The problem is that I often already have firefox on when I run that command, and sometimes (I am not sure exactly when) it would focus on the running Firefox. Do you know a solution for this? 
Thanks again

Comment: @Mr Woody: I'm not sure. Sorry. Maybe using the `pid` with AppleScript but it's something I'm not familiar with.